# Extract text using Jsoup result an empty textView

Tags: android, jsoup

I try to parse this page http://trestlebikepark.com/Lift_TrailStatus.html

my intention is to display it in a `Textview`, the open or closed status of the Trails,

I always receive an empty result or the app crashes.

I tried this code

```
Document docw = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Element div = docw.getElementById("#trestleTrails");
Elements tables = div.getElementsByTag("table");
Element table = tables.get(1);

String tit = table.getElementsByTag("tr").get(2).getElementsByTag("td").get(2).text();
```

Comment: well, did you debug this code? specially the last line, put a break point and inspect each segment until you find which one is empty, NULL or any thing else ... a log could be useful too

Answer (score 2):

you have several problems in the code above

general notes:

1- use div ID `trestleTrails` NOT `#trestleTrails` as below

`Element div = docw.getElementById("trestleTrails")`

2- indexing is `0-based`, which means first item have index 0 NOT 1
this

`Element table = tables.get(1)`
should become

`Element table = tables.get(0)`

as the div with id `trestleTrails` have only 1 table

3- the url you are trying to read does not contain what you expect
in that table there is only 1 row `tr` and it contains `th` not `td`

so in general this code works

```
Document docw = Jsoup.connect(srcLink).get();

Element div = docw.getElementById("trestleTrails");
Elements tables = div.getElementsByTag("table");
Element table = tables.get(0);

String tit = table.getElementsByTag("tr").get(0).getElementsByTag("th").get(0).text();
```

and output is `Trail Name`

Comment: Nice. Very useful.....So In the source code there is no row ( the row I looking for,  is in the tbody and in the source code the tbody is empty), but when in Chrome I use the "Inspect element" function I can see the trail status I need (Open or Closed) ... Then my question is: How I get this values to my String??

Comment: it looks that the table got populated after page loaded, some ajax call may be ... in order to get data you need to find out how exactly the table is filled. meanwhile if this answer fulfill the original question please accept it

Comment: How can I know that? how the page is loaded.And then get the results. Is necessary open a new question?

Comment: in a chrome browser, open developers tool. load the page then check the network tab, see all resources loaded, find one with some response (mostly JSON) that contains data filled in that table. from there on ... it's your turn :)